# Recall becomes 1 during training

Tags: neural-networks, regularization, precision-recall

I have a deep-learning network, a binary classification problem and I work with regularization.

During training recall becomes 1 (after the 4th or so epoch).

Now, I interpret that as follows:

My model just always predicting class 1 (FP = 0)
And since the final fscore is about equal to the "baseline" fscore (calculated as recall = 1 and precision = class1 / class1 + class0 ), I conclude that my model is basically learning nothing from the data.

Is this a correct interpretation and, if so, how to prevent that?
Is there just no useful information in my dataset?

Comment: Sounds like your sample is unbalanced, you could try undersampling or oversampling.

Comment: Oh ok.. yes its quite unbalanced; but only a little: Validation set: {0.0: 234, 1.0: 247}
Training set : {0.0: 1997, 1.0: 2322} I thought that is still acceptable

Comment: Well then unfortunately your interpretation might be correct. Unless you are working with images/audio etc. complicated data it would make sense to try some simpler methods first such as logistic regression, and if it achieves better results then there's probably something wrong with the deep learning model. If instead the results are bad, there might be no patterns in the data. Are you able to disclose what you are trying to classify?

Comment: I'm trying to classify corporate reports. I already know that quarterly reports are often shorter than yearly reports and that even among yearly reports there is a hugh variation in length (and content). Also, I know that a simple Bag-of-words method performs not very well (also when looking at the words) but with more complicated methods and regularization there appears this described error. I'll try oversampling today, but arguably my data is insufficient